# How to clear spatial reference identifier?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, coordinate-system, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-dbms

I created a table in oracle with a sde.st_geometry column. I followed the instructions of ArcGIS help to register the table into geodatabase.

My table creation statement is:

```
create table tbl_Comm_Cove 
(
ID                   NUMBER(10,0)         not null,
Name                 CHAR(200),
Devi_Num             CHAR(8),
Code                 CHAR(200),
Unit_Grid            CHAR(10),
GID                  CHAR(200),
Belo_Road            CHAR(200),
Inst_Time            DATE,
Mana_Depa_ID         NUMBER(10,0),
Owne_Depa            CHAR(200),
Main_Depa            CHAR(200),
Mate_ID              NUMBER(10,0),
Diam                 NUMBER(10,2),
Devi_Stat_ID         NUMBER(10,0),
"Desc"               CHAR(200),
Shap_ID              NUMBER(10,0),
Init_Time            DATE,
Chan_Time            DATE,
Note                 CLOB,
constraint PK_TBL_COMM_COVE primary key (ID)
);
/
alter table tbl_comm_cove add loc sde.st_geometry;
/
CREATE INDEX tbl_comm_cove_idx ON tbl_comm_cove(loc)
INDEXTYPE IS sde.st_spatial_index
PARAMETERS('st_grids=1,3,0 st_srid=0');
/
```

My registration command is:

```
sdelayer -o register -l tbl_comm_cove,loc -e p -t st_geometry -R 0 -C id,sde,0 -i sde:oracle11g -s localhost -u XXXXX-p XXXXX
```

As you can see, I assigned a SRID to my spatial information column "loc". 
Now I want to delete this assignment. I tried to do this in ArcCatalog by clicking the "Clear" button in the "XY coordinates" tab of the "Properites" dialog, but when I reopen the ArcCatalog, the assignment is still there.

What should I do?

My oracle version is 11.2.0, Arcgis version is 10.0.

Answer (score 2):

A spatial reference is not a nominal metadata property which can be changed at will.  Once set, it cannot be changed. Deletion is the only supported mechanism for changing an SRID. Once you register a table with ArcGIS, it should only be deleted with geodatabase-aware tools (Desktop, Python, ArcObjects .Net/Java).  When registered only from ArcSDE command-line tools, it's safest to drop tables with `sdetable -o delete`.

In addition, there are several non-standard aspects to your configuration:

- To operate with ArcGIS, the entity flags should be set to "np"
- It is almost always incorrect to use two levels of spatial indexing, and always incorrect to do so with point data.  One grid value, 3/4-5/4 of the average query window size will be more than sufficient.  Alternately, you can set the value to all zeros, and ArcGIS will calculate an appropriate grid size after initial loading.
- There is no reason you cannot create the table with the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY column in place
- A starting SDE-set ID value of 0 is incorrect (the minimum rowid value is 1)
- If you are planning to populate ID values on your own, the ID column should be registered as USER-set (not SDE-set); this will make the feature class unavailable for registration with the geodatabase, but the table will be available as a simple feature class.
- If the rowid column is to be SDE-set, it should be defined `NUMBER(38) NOT NULL`
- Specifying a primary key constraint before ArcSDE registration *may* cause registration to fail silently (it's hard to tell, since you've never stated what service pack of ArcSDE you have installed)
- The server (`-s`) option is ignored on Direct Connect, and can be omitted
- You should always drop the spatial index before bulk-loading tables (use LOAD-ONLY I/O mode when using ArcGIS tools for loading).

Comment: Thanks very much, sir.
Here is the packFinder output for my arcgis:
ArcGIS Desktop 10

ArcGIS Desktop 10 Chinese Supplement

ArcGIS Server 10 for the Java Platform

ArcGIS Server for the Java Platform 10 Chinese Supplement

ArcObjects SDK for the Java Platform 10.0

ArcGIS License Manager 10

ArcSDE for Oracle11g 64 bit 10

Comment: I tried to add a brand new table using the same approach that I metioned in my question without creating the index and the "-R 0" parameter in registration command. However, when I view the "Properties" dialog of the new table in ArcCatalog, the "XY Coordinates" tab still contain the assignment. Why?

Comment: Zero is the default, not that it should ever be used.  Instead, you should use a correct coordinate reference.

Comment: I got it, sir. thanks again for your continuous help:-)

Comment: I still have one question. In my oracle, there are two spatial reference system tables: SPATIAL_REFERENCE and ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE. According to "arcgis server help", when I use oracle st_geometry storage, it's the ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE table that should be used to store spatial references. However, when I register the table in command-line with "-R 7", it's pointing to the spatial reference with SRID 7 in SPATIAL_REFERENCE table. Why?

Comment: Because that's the way it's supposed to work (each to their own)

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow you, sir. According to "ArcGIS Server Help", it should point to spatial references in ST_SPATIAL_REFERENCE table, shouldn't it? Both tables have a reference corresponding to SRID 7.

Comment: No, the ST type references the ST table; the layer references the other table (which also has to support other types). This is a very different question.